# Google Sheet Script Not Reliably Running

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've gotten to the point where I have a pretty solid script that:

1) Takes data from a new data tab and posts it to an existing data tab
2) Clears data from the new data tab
3) Deletes duplicates from the existing data tab

When I originally put this script in, it worked great. But after running it a few times, it seems to stall at the de-duping portion of the script. So when I run it, the first two scripts run, but not the third. If I select the de-dupe script to run on it's own, it works just fine.

Has anyone else seen this issue? Is there any way to tweak the script to have a more reliable run so that it will always process all three scripts?

Not sure how to optimize from there.

```
function Run(){
  insert();
  clear1();
  removeDuplicates();
}
function insert() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getSheetByName('Candidate Refresh'); // change here
  var des = ss.getSheetByName('Candidate Listing'); // change here

  var sv = source
    .getDataRange()
    .getValues();
  sv.shift();
  des.insertRowsAfter(1, sv.length);
  des.getRange(2, 1, sv.length, source.getLastColumn()).setValues(sv);
}
function clear1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Candidate Refresh');
  sheet.getRange('A2:K100').clearContent()
}
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows=sheet.getLastRow();
  var firstColumn=sheet.getRange(1, 2, rows, 1).getValues();
  firstColumn = firstColumn.map(function(e){return e[0]})
  var uA=[];
  for (var i=rows;i>0;i--) {
    if (uA.indexOf(firstColumn[i-1])!=-1) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i);
    }else{
      uA.push(firstColumn[i-1]);
    }
  }
}
```

All three scripts should fire when the Run script is played.

Comment: Are you sure your functions are not throwing an error?  In the script editor View -> Execution transcript after running your script. This looks suspicious des.getRange(2, 1, sv.length, source.getLastColumn()).setValues(sv)

Comment: Can you share a line or two of your data?

Comment: I notice that your only clearing the first 99 lines.  Perhaps you have a lot of data below that's making the script run more slowly.

Comment: @TheWizEd it doesn't appear that the functions are throwing an error and I watch in after playing it. Also, if I just play the de-dupe script on its own, it does fine.

Comment: @Cooper There's actually not a lot of data, maybe like 30-40 rows at this point. You can find the example data here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KGXZJ1A2cutPdzg1A4D4k1SI52z3FyQZwM-kmO5EGps/edit#gid=0

Comment: It runs okay for me.

Comment: @Cooper that's the thing, it ran great for me the first few times. As I started doing more and more run tests, it stopped doing the de-depe and I would need to process the de-dupe portion of the script separately. I'm wondering if it's just a glitch.

Comment: I removed the clear and ran it about twenty times and I see no problems.  I can't fix what I can't find.  If you can provide me with [mcve] then I will fix it.

Comment: There does seem to be some inconsistency regarding page names.  The examples sheets are called Candidate Listing and Candidate Research but in the code there are only Candidate List and Candidate Refresh.  I assumed that Candidate Refresh is actually meant to be Candidate Research.  So perhaps you can explain that further.  Perhaps that's part of the problem